# Implementing a custom Login Handler

Tags: authentication, meteor, account

I'm trying to use the SmartPackage [accounts-anonymous](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous), and it was using what looked like an older API:

```
Meteor.accounts.registerLoginHandler(...)
```

To the newer one (forked at [dougnukem/meteor-accounts-anonymous](https://github.com/dougnukem/meteor-accounts-anonymous)):

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler(...)
```

But when using the standard accounts-ui package it just says:

> No login services configured

Then when I hookup a button to force the anonymous login:

```
  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // LOGIN ANONYMOUSLY
      Meteor.loginAnonymously();
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("You pressed the button");
        console.log("LOGGED IN ANONYMOUSLY AS: " + Meteor.userId());
      }
    }
  });
```

I get an error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onCreateUserHook'
    at app/packages/accounts-anonymous/anonymous_server.js:10:25
    at tryAllLoginHandlers (app/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:33:25)
    at _.find._.detect (app/packages/underscore/underscore.js:142:20)
    at Array.some (native)
    at _.some._.any (app/packages/underscore/underscore.js:193:59)
    at Function._.find._.detect (app/packages/underscore/underscore.js:141:5)
    at tryAllLoginHandlers (app/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:31:7)
    at Meteor.methods.login (app/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:12:20)
    at app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:298:30
    at _.extend.withValue (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:31:19)
```

Comment: I whipped up accounts-anonymous in a couple of hours and then promptly decided not to use it. I'd happily accept PRs or give up control of the package, but I wouldn't expect it to work in it's current incarnation.

Comment: I've created something similar to accounts-anonymous that uses a more recent API: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-accounts-testing